# javascript for loop produces error in output

Tags: javascript, for-loop, counter

The below for loop produces an error in the html output, I substituted with other function and the html output was fine, so I'm convinced its this function. I also recreated it in an ide substituting $("#car").html(year); for console.log(year); and it produced the correct output. What is the problem with this function?

```
function cgr() {
for (var year = 0; (churn * total_customer) < leadcon; year++) {
    total_customer = total_customer + leadcon;
     if ((churn * total_customer) >= leadcon) {
            $("#car").html(year);
        }else {
    $("#car").html("something is wrong");
    };
}
```

}

full script can be found here: http://pastebin.com/DcDKNfux

Comment: What error? What was expected that this doesn't do? What other function did you use that worked?

Comment: you are changing html of `$("#car")` in a for loop without a `break;` statement after success !(why?) .

Comment: What would the break do? If the condition is met the loop stops.

Comment: It seems this error is being triggered: function ShowValue (selector, v) {
        $(selector).html(isNaN(v) ? "Error" : "$" + Round2Cent(v)); 
    }

Comment: Sure, when you call the  $("#car").html() function with a string ("something is wrong") instead of a number, then isNaN() for the string returns true, and that function just outputs "Error."  I think that's not really directly related to your question, though, which is why you get to the "something is wrong" part of the code, right?

Comment: I have removed that else statement altogether and it works in the test javascript ide, but getting it to work inside the larger script is still not happening.

Answer (score 1):

The loop condition, (churn * total_customer) < leadcon, seems to have no relation to the loop counter "year" which is initialized at zero and then incremented.  Where are the variables churn, total_customer, and leadcon initialized, and to what values?

In any case, it's completely logical for the loop condition  (churn * total_customer) < leadcon to be true when the iteration of the loop is entered, and then for the  if condition (churn * total_customer) >= leadcon) to also be true after the total_customer variable is modified with essentially total_customer += leadcon.

But it's hard to know what the expected results are, especially without more information about the input data.

I would add more logging in the function so that you can trace what's happening, something like this:

```
function cgr() {
for (var year = 0; (churn * total_customer) < leadcon; year++) {
    $("#car").html("entering loop, year=" + year + ", churn=" + churn + ", total_customer=" + total_customer + ", leadcon=" + leadcon);
    total_customer = total_customer + leadcon;
    $("#car").html("after mod, total_customer=" + total_customer);
     if ((churn * total_customer) >= leadcon) {
            $("#car").html(year);
        }else {
    $("#car").html("something is wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: The variables are defined in the script

Comment: Yes, they're declared in the script, but I don't know what values they have, nor am I in a position to debug your entire client-side script.  If you log the values like I suggested, then it will be more obvious what they are, and presumably why they're being handled in a way different from what you expect.

Comment: The values are entered by the user in the fields of the DOM.

Comment: Sure, but again, I don't have any way of testing the function without hard-coding the parameters.  What values are you using which cause the failure?  Again, logging that stuff somehow, even if you can't log a string with the $("#car").html function, would go a long way to debugging this.

Comment: See this link for the UI, the function should generate the result for the field "Customer Acquisition Rate". I have tested it many different ways but can not get it to output. http://jsfiddle.net/RT6Yn/